# detecting Download file dialog?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

is there any way i could detect opening of download file dialog box on web pages like  hyperlink click event occurs and download file dialog box appears.... ??

and can i edit the filename in it ...... like attaching some website name along with filename .... so when the user download any file it automatically rename in to website-filename.pdf etc pro-grammatically

can we use input tag for it ?? or have to make customcontrols for it ??
thanks if any help provided

take care.
regards,
newbiefreak

Comment: People, what is with the downvote fest?

Comment: why giving minus votes ...  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make a hyperlink with its href to a regular file, your browser will prompt to download it.

As for renaming the file, all you could do is create a special page which sends the file contents and correct headers, and specifying another name. You'll have to send the `content-disposition` header, as such:

> Content-disposition: attachment; filename=**yourfilename.extension**

Comment: thanks with it i can set default file name to website-xyz.txt .. 

one part of my problem is solved
but with it i cant pick up the orginally filename like xyz.pdf or abc.txt 

by using it fixed my download link filename and its extension to xyz.txt 
any solution for this problem

Comment: @NewbieFreak - They told you how to do it. You need to use serverside code!

Answer (score 2):

You can send a Content-disposition header to force a file downlaod box and specify a default filename.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519

Answer (score 1):

In regards to editing the filename:

HTML5 introduces a new attribute for `a` tags: `download`.

Using it forces browsers that support the attribute to prompt for a file download, rather than navigating to or attempting to open the linked file.

Also, whatever you value you assign to `download` will replace the file's actual name.

Source and demo: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download